# App that can sync PDF annotations only (without PDF file itself) across multiple devices (Android)

Tags: android, pdf, file-synchronization, pdf-viewer, synchronization

I want an app that can sync PDF annotations only without the PDF file itself. Because PDF file itself can be big in size (e.g. 200MB) and no need to upload / download the whole pdf file every time a sync is needed.

It's good to have the app able to sync pdf annotations between Android devices only (however if it can sync between Windows/Mac PC also it will be a plus).

An example of an app that syncs annotations only (but for epub books only, not PDF) is Moon+ Reader for Android, it syncs annotations only (which are small in size) without needing to sync the books files themselves.